# NBO Calculation failing (ATDIAG DISCRD)

Tags: computational-chemistry

I'm trying to perform NBO calculations on a bimetallic complex to evaluate bond orders. However, while I've previously done NBO calculations to obtain partial charges which worked without problems, the NBO calculations for this complex just outright fail.

I get the error message on top of the NBO output claiming:

```
WORTH: ATDIAG and DISCRD failed to remove linear dependence in the PNAOs
```

Unfortunately, I can't find anything regarding those abbreviations in the official NBO manual or elsewhere online. Maybe someone of you has an idea how this problem could be solved.

I am using NBO 7.0 for all my calculations, in case this changes anything.

Comment: Unanswered thread on NBO forum: http://nboinc.chem.wisc.edu/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=183. From what I could find in searching around, the only suggestion given was to shrink the basis set you are using. What basis set are you using for these calculations?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've used def2TZVPP till this point, I'll start a calculation with the slightly smaller def2TZVP and report back if that has solved the problem.

Comment: @Tyberius this did indeed solve the problem. Would like to mark your comment as the solution, can't figure out how to do that though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [only thread](http://nboinc.chem.wisc.edu/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=213) I could find that had some discussion of this on the NBO forum was related to using the NBO interface in Gaussian and was likely about an earlier version of NBO based on the discussion being from 2016.

However, the answerer there seems to be an NBO developer and he mentions that these linear dependency failures can often be resolved by shrinking the basis. Hopefully this should not affect the overall results much, as they suggest that NBO properties converge very quickly with basis set size:

> NBO descriptors converge nicely as the basis set is extended. Double-zeta is usually really good, triple-zeta is better, and you'll likely not learn much more by going to quadruple-zeta or beyond.